# IntelliJ IDEA - Caret column color

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, customization

IntelliJ IDEA has Caret row setting (Editor -> Color Scheme -> General)  where it is possible to set foreground and background colour for the whole line where the caret is positioned.

Is there a way how to achieve the same, but for the column?

Answer (score 0):

No, IntelliJ IDEA can only highlight the current row, there is no option to do the same for the current column. Feature request with the real world use case [is welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).